# converting cells into text boxes where check box is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am using mysql and asp.net with c#. I have a grid view which will display dynamically selected table data. I am able to display the data of selected table. In the first column i have added a check box and a Button outside Grid view. When user selects Check box and clicks on button, the selected rows must turn into text boxes. I am able to find the seleted check box, but i'm unable to convert the cells into text boxes. Here's my code:

```
     int n = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count;

    for( int i=0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
    {

        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
        bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked;

        {
            for( int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                TextBox txt = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j]).Text;

            }
        }
    }
```

At this line: `TextBox txt = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j]).Text;` 
i get a warning :
 `cannot convert 'System.Web.UI.Controls.TableCell' to type 'System.Web.UI.Controls.TextBox` 
I am unable to resolve this. Please help. Thank you

Comment: There are built-in functionalities in order to make a gridview data editable; I would suggest that you investigate this before reinventing the wheel. Here's an example in .NET 2.0, but I don't think there are many changes to this in most recent versions : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0

Comment: TextBox txt = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j]).Text;?????? how are you trying to Convert cell text which is String to a Control of type TextBox??????

Comment: The warning said it all. Please upload aspx page.

Comment: The problem is that i am using mysql and i am binding the table to my grid dynamically. that is, i have a drop down list from where user selects the table. So i will not know the column names at all. I have to do every thing dynamically. That's why i couldn't make use of edit delete buttons. I tried to add edit button with following properties in aspx `<asp:CommandField showEditButton="true">`  i wrote a function for`OnRowEditing="grid_Edit` . In the function i wrote: `GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex; fill_grid();`When i run it, it shows edit button but when i click on it, nthg happens

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

You can remove one or few lines based on your hands-on with C#.

Concept is, you should create a TextBox, assign cell text that textbox and then Add that newly created textbox to child controls of Grid Cell of particular row.

Mark this solution if you found useful.

```
    bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked;
    if(isChecked)
    {
        for( int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            TextBox tbForCell = new TextBox();
            tbForCell.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text = "";
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Controls.Add(tbForCell);
        }
    }
```

If you want to avoid the TextBox to appear in CheckBox Column please initialise loop variable j with 1 instead of 0.

```
        for( int j=1;j<n;j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method call is finding the *cell*. The Textbox is a control contained within the cell. Try something like this instead:

```
TextBox txt = ((TextBox) GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].FindControl("textbox name")).Text;
```

The `FindControl` method is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx).

Also take @Bartdude's advice about using editable gridviews. If one will work at least as well as what you're trying to hand-roll, it's worth the time learning how to use it.

Comment: Yes i would have tried it. But i do not know the exact column name because i am displying the grid dynamically based on the drop down list selected item

Comment: Do you actually have a textbox in there? If not, and it's just a plain cell, I think you can use `string txt = ((TableCell)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j]).Text;` to get the cell contents. But that won't work if there really is a TextBox in there, and I can't tell from the posted code if there is or not.